# "Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: TLS/SSL error: Success (0)", with ruby,mysql2,mariadb

Tags: ruby, mariadb

Recently upgrade my ruby version from 2.6 to 2.7
And I started seeing this error randomly when app is trying to run a select query, and database connection fails.
"Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: TLS/SSL error: Success (0)"
I use mysql2 and activercord

DB: Mariadb
I use sslca to connect DB

Not able to replicate this error intentionally, Tried to increase the load but it fails with number of connections error(which is valid)
Upgraded to ruby 3 and mysql2/activerecord to latest version but still same issue
Any insight on what this error exactly indicates might help me analyse further?

Comment: With what code? How are you getting this error? What would we have to do to try and reproduce it?

Comment: When running any select query, randomly this error is thrown. How to reproduce it? That is what am not able to figure out yet, just ruby upgrade started triggering this. If found any will post it here. "TLS/SSL error: Success (0)" looks like DB error, if any what that means would be helpful for me to debug further